# Centering images (both vertically and horizontally) in Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am using Bootstrap 4 carousel and I am trying to center an image both vertically and horizontally. The following is my code together with the styling:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200/c0392b/000">                      
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>



#myCarousel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.carousel-indicators>li {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #213B74;
}

.carousel-item {
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-item img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

For now, I have only added one carousel item for testing. The image is being centered horizontally. However, I have tried to set the display attribute for the image to block and its margin to auto but it's still not being centered vertically. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

I have tried looking into other questions related to this, but I still didn't find the answer that I'm looking for. In case this question is a duplicate, I would gladly appreciate if you could tell me which answer should I be looking into.

Thanks

Comment: You may refer the following web page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go, you will need to add a `<div>` within the `.carousel-item`, and within that div your image will be placed. We are taking this mediator div to apply the `flex` centering effect.

If you try to apply `flex` classes such as `d-flex` on `.carousel-item` the carousel will not work as expected.

here I have added the `<div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">` which places the image within it to exact center of the div. Also you will have to give the div `min-height` equivalent to the `.carousel-item` **OR** some standard height for you carousel, so that it don't collapse if the inner image is smaller in size.

you can get to know more about flex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), also if you would like to try out with some examples go [here](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/css-flexbox).

```css
#myCarousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.carousel-indicators>li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #213B74;
}

.carousel-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.parent {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x200/c0392b/000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100/c0392b/000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="parent d-flex justify-content-center">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150/c0392b/000">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your problem using the following code for the css:

```
#myCarousel {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;    
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.carousel-indicators>li {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #213B74;
}

.carousel-item {
   height: 100%;
}

.carousel-item img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

So first of all, I gave the carousel a height of `100vh` to fill the total height of screen (You can give it a fixed height as well). I then made the carousel-item `height: 100%` in order to make it the full height of carousel and then applied the carousel-item img code as above in order to move the image to the center both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `align-items-center` & `align-content-center` Bootstrap 4 flex classes. See example below :

```css
.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="h-100 w-100 d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center align-content-center">
    <div class="mx-auto">

      Content

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```